# Why does an editing method in a List property use the get accessor?

Tags: c#, properties

I have a property of type `List<T>`, and I want to update a database whenever it's updated.

At first, I thought I could just update the database in the property's set accessor, but after some testing, I realized that methods like `Add()` and `Remove()` only use the get accessor, not the set one.

Why is this, and what can I do to work around it?

The class containing this property implements an interface which requires a `List`. Although I can change the property's type to `BindingList` in the interface, not all implementing members need to know when the property is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Your property shouldn't have a setter to begin with. That property relates to the `List` object itself, not the items in the `List`. A setter would be used to replace the existing `List` object with a completely new `List` object. In order to call `Add` or `Remove` on the existing `List` object, you need to get that object from the property first, hence the getter is what is executed.

If you need to know when the existing collection object changes, only the collection itself can do that. That means using a `BindingList<T>` as you suggest, or an `ObservableCollection<T>`. The property itself should be read-only, e.g.

```cs
public ObservableCollection<object> Objects { get; } = new ObservableCollection<object>();

private void Objects_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

and:

```cs
Objects.CollectionChanged += Objects_CollectionChanged;
```

Comment: I can't use a `BindingList` or `ObservableCollection` because only this implementer of the interface needs to know when the list is updated - as far as I know, if I want to use one of those in this implementing type, I'll have to change it in the interface for all implementers.

Comment: @Moustache, if you want to be notified when the list changes, you need to use a list type that will provide that notification. The `List<T>` class doesn't do so. You need to change the type to something that does or you can't be notified. It's that simple. One option could be to inherit `List<T>` and add that functionality. Everyone else would then be able to treat that property as though it were `List<T>`. I'm not sure that's possible though, as `List<T>` was not created with the intent of being extended, so it may not provide the hooks you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by restating the question using code snippets so we have actual identifier names to work with.

---

You have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<string> MyList {get; set;} = new List<string>();
}
```

And you have an instance of `MyClass`:

```
var myInstance = new MyClass();
```

You then have code like this:

```
myInstance.MyList.Add("foo");
```

The question is why this uses the `get` accessor for the `MyList` property instead of the `set`, even though it changes the `List<string>` property.

---

The answer is the code starts from the `myInstance` object and then needs to **GET** the `List<string>` object referred to by the `MyList` property so it can call that list's `Add()` method. It **doesn't matter** that the `Add()` method changes the list. As far as the property access is concerned, you are still **getting** the reference, and nothing else.

So what is the `set` accessor for, then? Well... setting the reference. So now let's say you do this:

```
myInstance.MyList = new List<string>();
```

This uses the `set` accessor, because *it sets a new value to the actual property* and not just a property or member of the property. And now that you understand when the `set` accessor is actually called, hopefully that helps clarify *why* the `get` accessor is used in other situations: you did **not** assign a new value to the property.

---

Finally, this should raise the question of whether you want a `set` accessor for the property at all.

For many classes, completely changing a List used by the class  is likely to break assumptions for other related aspects of the class. That is, you're probably better off declaring the property like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<string> MyList {get; private set;} = new List<string>();
}
```

or like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<string> MyList {get;} = new List<string>();
}
```

Because, again, anything you want to do with *that specific list instance* is a `get` operation, rather than a `set`, and so the `set` access is not really needed **or even helpful.**

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to create and unit test the 4 CRUD methods to work on the list as you often have to do. But, if you really want a workaround you could use IList:

```
public class DatabaseList<T>: IList<T>
    where T: class, new()
{
    private List<T> _list;
        
    public DatabaseList()
    {
        _list = new List<T>();
        // populate from current database content?
    }

    public new void Add(T item)
    {
        _list.Add(item);
        // and do database Insert
    }
    
    // and the other 12 members of IList...
    //   which makes the 4 CRUD methods sounds like a lot less testing
}
```